# How Can I Creat Method do This Job?

Tags: arrays

I want create method that return an array which contains exactly the same numbers as the given array, but rearranged so that every 3 is immediately followed by a 4.

Do not move the 3's, but every other number may move. The array contains the same number of 3's and 4's, every 3 has a number after it that is not a 3 or 4, and a 3 appears in the array before any 4.

Example:

```
problem({1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1}) → {1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4}
problem({3, 2, 2, 4}) → {3, 4, 2, 2}
```

thanks .

Comment: Do you have a specific programming language in mind? For example there are various array sorting functions in `php`

Comment: is this a homework task?

Answer (score 1):

Set i = 0, j = 0. Then you repeat the following:

Find the first 3 at an index ≥ i which is not followed by a 4. If none are found, you succeeded. If the 3 is the last number in the array or followed by a 3, you failed. Now find the first 4 at an index ≥ j which is not preceded by a 3. If none are found, you fail. Otherwise set i = location of the 3, j = location of the 4, exchange the objects at positions i+1 and j, set i = i + 2 and j = j + 1, and repeat.

I don't like writing code that depends on promises about the data that I don't verify myself, so this will work whatever is in the array.